# Android - Kotlin - How to get camera to place Bitmap thumbnail in same list that the button is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

newb question here. I have two lists, each of which have a "take photo" button. Once a photo is taken, I'd like to place the thumbnail in the recycler view of the button that is clicked.

For example. if button 1 is clicked, place thumbnail in list one. if button 2 is clicked, place photo in list 2. It seems like an easy task but I am having issues with it.

Currently, when I take a pic, it goes into both lists. if I remove one of the recyclerviews. the pic will go into whichever list of the button that was clicked first.

is there a way to set the onActivityResult to place the pic in the respective's clicked button list?

here is my code:
**list1.xml**

```
                android:id="@+id/list1RecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/list2PicsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="list1 button"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">
            </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

**list2xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list2RecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/list2PicsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="list2 button"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

**activity**

```
class TakePhotosActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1

    private lateinit var list1 : RecyclerViewAdapter
    private lateinit var list2: RecyclerViewAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photos)

        initRecyclerView()
        list1PicsButton.setOnClickListener{
            takePhotos();
        }


        list2PicsButton.setOnClickListener{
            takePhotos();
        }

private fun initRecyclerView() {
        list1.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@TakePhotosActivity, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
            photoAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
            adapter = photoAdapter
        }


        list2.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@TakePhotosActivity, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
            buddyAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
            adapter = buddyAdapter
        }

    }

private fun takePhotos() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap

            list1.addPhoto(imageBitmap)
            list2.addPhoto(imageBitmap)


        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_1` and `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_2`.

Comment: @blackapps, if you want to post this as an answer, I'll check it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different request codes for the actions to distinguish them.